# Is there a way export a JFrame with images?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

We made a project on netbeans, and added a an image as background (by adding an icon to the JLabel) but when exporting the frame to my other team members the image does not appear. Do you have a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "exporting the frame"?

Comment: I meant exporting the project into a zip file

Comment: You need to make sure the image is included in your zip file with with all your java source/class files. You also need to make sure the image is in a directory contained on the classpath. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

Comment: By 'zip file' DYM an executable Jar file? How are the images loaded?